# Did I get the concept of declaration, definition and initialization right?

Tags: c++

Sorry in advance for possible duplicate. I learned that declaration puts a variable as "a thing" that is available in the code, definition would be something that is either initialized or not, for example `int foo = 0` or

> void function() {
>
> }

would be defined, but not initialized, since foo practically does nothing since it has 0 assigned and function has opened curly braces, so both of them do take up memory.
And something like `int foo = 5` would be initialized since it stores number 5. Did I get it right? Sorry for possibly bad formating as well.

Comment: Why would `int foo = 5;` be initialization but `int foo = 0;` not?

Comment: @Kevin Wasn't so sure about it, but aren't most definitions initializations as well?

Answer (score 1):

When you put

```
int foo = 0;
```

You are assigning a number to foo so foo is initialized here if you don't want to initialize foo, You have to say

```
int foo;
```

For functions is like this too

```
void function(); // declare

void function(){

} // initialize
```

Comment: Interesting sidenote: For classes with user-declared constructors, it's pretty much impossible to declare them without defining them.